# Can I sync files between computers without the cloud storage?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I am looking to drop Windows Live Mesh and have been playing around with Ubuntu One. So far I love it, but I can't seem to find a way to sync folders between my computers and bypass the online (5GB) storage. I have about 150GB I need to sync between 5 computers, only about 4GB worth of it needs to be on the cloud.

Is this possible? I remember reading somewhere that in 11.10, this might be possible. If this feature is not implemented yet, does anyone have any idea when we can expect to see this?

Comment: it is possible with help of few tools like rsync

Answer (score 1):

There is a command-line program called rsync which is able to efficiently synchronize data between different computers over a network (or between folders on the same machine). If you're not afraid of command line, you can use that straight away.

There are also numerous wrappers around rsync, such as Conduit, GRSync, gtkrsync, unison, luckybackup, mrb and possibly others. They all available in Ubuntu repositories so you can just install them via Software Center and see which one you like most.

Those applications are not specific for Ubuntu 11.10 and have been available for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible 
try apps such as conduit or unison
or check here

[How to sync files/data between two PCs on a home network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15644/how-to-sync-data-between-two-pcs)