# How to sync two computers daily

Tags: sync

I have two computers running Ubuntu; one is my work computer and the other is my home computer. I'd like them to behave as basically the same computer. Any programs installed or files changes on one computer would be reflected in the other computer. So for example when I come home, I could press 'sync', and the changes made during the day on my work computer would appear on my home computer.

Is this possible?

Comment: Closely related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15644/how-to-sync-files-data-between-two-pcs-on-a-home-network and http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools

Answer (score 2):

I do no believe that is actually possible as you are describing it, but you can achieve much of the same with the following:

### <s>Ubuntu One</s>/Dropbox

Keep your files in sync at all times with a cloud service. <s>Ubuntu comes with Ubuntu One preinstalled and it lets you monitor any folder. Cheap to upgrade the space also.</s>
If you are a dropbox-user, that will also work on Ubuntu!

### Ubuntu Software Center Sync

If you open the Ubuntu Software Center and go to

**File -> Sync Between Computers**

or, use the dash like so:

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>, Write "sync" → Profit!

I am not sure if you can automatically sync from the Software Center, but you can see what items are NOT (and are) installed on one computer compared to another.

I understand that none of these is as simple as you would want it to, but you can get pretty far with these solutions (I use them every day!)